# UWP: Transparent Grid with MapControl beneath is flickering

Tags: background, grid, maps, uwp, flicker

In my Windows 10 UWP app there is a view, where a `MapControl` is partially (at the top) covered by a `Grid`. This `Grid` has cockpit-like elements in it (e.g. speedometer) and has a semi-transparent background-brush (`#CC6A6E4D`).

The actual problem is, that this background-brush is flickering, whenever one is interacting with the `MapControl`. Weird thing about this is, that this issue exclusively works on just one of my three test devices (Lumia 550) and only is present in portrait-mode (but not in landscape-mode).

An example-layout, where I've got that issue would be this:

```
<Grid>
    <maps:MapControl
        Name="MainMapControl"/>

    <Grid
        Height="50"
        VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#CC6A6E4D" />
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to just make it Black (or your desired color) and set the Opacity of the Grid to make it transparent?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Unfortunately the flickering-effect persists.